# Google API returns complex NSDictionary object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, google-places-api

When I parse the data of google API for local police station details, it returns an `NSDictionary` in it with a complex form:

```
result =     (
            {
        geometry =             {
            location =                 {
                lat = "22.72187";
                lng = "75.8741";
            };
        };
        icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png";
        id = 5bf224eb03bee960670c048f7dcdb2684d6aed1f;
        name = "Name Police Station";
        reference = "CoQBgAAAACG6clYx-1ycnenczJfECFggwSCVzxqFR8GKwMYpA1QbP1VTRIgHHYNXW7z0kOw9IRuV9gKJ-ES19tf46CcwUShwT_lznIX36sx_F8aKFjYE3APa0zNWRxSGY0fDQ95HwinR9HXhTWeL0ncPHSLo9cL9FB8OlBJF-tYNRP5ZThuMEhCQH0lSxrelWOd";
        type =             (
            police,
            establishment
        );
        vicinity = "Yeshwant Niwas Road, Sanghi Colony";
    },
```

Here, I got many objects of geometry, id, name.

How do I use this data in a simple `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`?

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSArray>Object objectatIndex:index];
```

then `dict` would return value for key like it would return `[[dict objectforkey:@"name"];`.

Comment: Looks more like an array of dictionary objects to me.  Anyway it should be no issue to enumerate the array and dictionary elements within it and as you don't suggest which bits of data you want, I doubt you'll get a *very* useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple documentation helped me to solve above problem:

I use this code to solve above dictionary problem-

```
NSArray *arryDict = [dictPoliceStatin objectForKey:@"result"];

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [arryDict objectEnumerator];
NSDictionary *anObject;

while (anObject = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    /* code to act on each element as it is returned */

     NSMutableDictionary *diceGloable = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



    [diceGloable setObject:[[[anObject objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] forKey:@"lat"];
     [diceGloable setObject:[[[anObject objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] forKey:@"lng"];
    [diceGloable setObject:[anObject objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
    [diceGloable setObject:[anObject objectForKey:@"vicinity"] forKey:@"vicinity"];

    [arrayMapValues addObject:diceGloable];

}
```

ObjectEnumerator helped here, arrayMapsValues is the NSMutablearray class object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **FTGooglePlacesAPI** library I'm currently working on. This is a complete library for interaction with the Google Places API using simple, block-based Objective-C interface.

There is no readme or how-to at the moment as I don't consider it final/released yet. But it works pretty fine and there is a very detailed, well-commented example project.

You can find the library here: https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTGooglePlacesAPI

---

Or you can utilize `valueForKeyPath:` method of some collections from `NSFoundation`, which is often overlooked, but very powerful.

Example:

```
NSDictionary *firstItem = results[0];
NSNumber *lat = [firstItem valueForKeyPath:@"geometry.location.lat"];
```